# Hacer click a un boton para abrir un archivo pdf en python y QT

Tags: python, pyqt

Soy novato programando en `Python` y mi idea es que al hacer click en el botón que llame "Botonawg" se abra un archivo `pdf`. Me gustaría que esto funcionara tanto en `windows` como en sistemas `UNIX`.

Yo uso `GNU-Linux ARCh`. 
Hice este código pero me da el siguiente error:

> NameError: name 'QtCore' is not defined.

Código:

```
import sys
import webbrowser #para abrir archivos
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5 import uic
"""from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt"""

"""#Clase heredada de QMainWindow (Constructor de ventanas)"""
class Ventana(QMainWindow):
 #Método constructor de la clase
 def __init__(self):
  #Iniciar el objeto QMainWindow
  QMainWindow.__init__(self)
  #Cargar la configuración del archivo .ui en el objeto
  uic.loadUi("MiProyecto.ui", self)
  self.setWindowTitle("Ktronix")

  #Abrir tabla AWG


"""
  def openFile(file):
  if sys.platform == 'linux2':
     subprocess.call(["xdg-open", file])
  else:
     os.startfilefile)

""" 

QtCore.QObject.connect(self.uiself.Botonawg, QtCore.SIGNAL ('clicked()'), webbrowser.open_new(r'/home/ronal/ktronic/awg.pdf'))
```

Agradecería de su ayuda.

Comment: Estás usando `QtCore` en la última línea pero no lo has importado previamente. Por otra parte, si quieres que la lectura del pdf sea compatible en diferentes sistemas operativos no puedes incluir la ruta de forma explícita y deberías incluir un QFileDialog a no ser que sepas donde estará ese pdf en todos los sistemas operativos y detectes el sistema operativo previamente...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aparentemente tu error es que no importas el modulo QtCore de PyQt5, ademas recomiendo hacer la conecciones dentro de `__init__()`

```
import sys
import subprocess

from PyQt5 import QtCore

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5 import uic

"""#Clase heredada de QMainWindow (Constructor de ventanas)"""
class Ventana(QMainWindow):
    #Método constructor de la clase
    def __init__(self):
        #Iniciar el objeto QMainWindow
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        #Cargar la configuración del archivo .ui en el objeto
        uic.loadUi("MiProyecto.ui", self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Ktronix")

        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.Botonawg, QtCore.SIGNAL ('clicked()'), this.abrirTabla)

    def abrirTabla(this):
        this.openFile(r'/home/ronal/ktronic/awg.pdf') 

    #Abrir tabla AWG
    def openFile(this, file):
        if sys.platform == 'linux2':
            #Linux detectado
            subprocess.call(["xdg-open", file])
        elif sys.platform == 'darwin':
            #MacOSx detectado
            subprocess.call(["open", file])
        elif sys.platform.startswith('win'):
            #Windows detectado
            subprocess.call(["start", file])
```

En realidad no existe un comando universal y portable para decirle al sistema operativo que abra un archivo con su aplicacion determinada, sin embargo, estos comandos son muy parecidos. En windows el comando `start`, para la mayoria de distribuciones linux `xdg-open` y por ultimo para sistemas Apple con MacOS `open`.

Editado: 
Se eliminó la linea:  `import webbrowser #para abrir archivos`

Comment: ¿en que parte usas`webbrowser`? ¿es necesario importarlo?

Comment: En ninguna parte, como copie y pegue el codigo de la pregunta original. Pero en efecto, no es necesario importarlo. Supongo que si deseas abrir el archivo con el navegador puedes usar `webbrowser` en vez de la llamada la system con `subprocess`

Comment: Entonces te recomiendo eliminarlo :-), es mejor dar una respuesta limpia .

Comment: @eyllanesc listo, gracias por el comentario :).